# Get-NetNeighbor for other routers in various sites (Determining active devices connected)

Tags: networking, powershell, arp

First post here, usually partial to StackOverflow, but this isn't exactly code related so I figured I'd drop here. I'm looking to get the arp table of routers within our network at various sites. I'm not 100% sure on the best method of placing myself in that position without actually shelling into the router, which defeats the purpose of the process I'm trying to automate.

Any ideas how I can do so? Feel free to ask questions for clarity, I'm not sure what information would be most beneficial to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the routers you are using there should be tools to ssh to the router and get the info for you. F.ex. ansible, netconf, cisco_cmd etc. From my experience getting info automatically out of old Ciscos reliably is quite hard though...

Comment: I'll accept this as it's absolutely correct and some offers I've found in my search as well, however, I found that the caching on our arp tables versus how I can use our access point controller to leverage client data to find devices connected since a WLAN profile on APs is the only way for foreign devices to connect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: also, what tells you about a router's neighbors is: 1. its routing table and 2. cdp info, that will tell you what layer 2 device are connected to it.